# Is there any way to identify the password protected binary documents before the ingestion into MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

We are pushing some binary documents like word and pdf documents in our application but some of binary documents could be protected with passwords. We need to validate the binary documents before the ingestion into MarkLogic so that we can throw the exception for those password protected binary documents. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most performant, but you could first verify that you are able to open and read the PDF files, using the `xdmp:document-filter()` function.

If the PDF is password protected, it will throw an exception. Use a try/catch, and only insert the document if there are no exceptions.

```
  try {
    let $_ := xdmp:document-filter($doc)
    return xdmp:document-insert($uri, $doc)
  } catch ($exception) {
    (: failed to parse the encrypted PDF, don't insert :)
  }
```